# Updating/changing Kivy labels

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying for quite a while to figure out how to update labels using python/kivy, I can set the label, but I can't get it to update after it's been set.
This is my python code:

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    status = StringProperty()
    status = 'Text_Status' # This works.
    def updatelabel(self, ):
        # When I call this function, this does not update the label.
        self.status='Text_status no.2'
```

And this is my .kv file

```
Label:
    id: status
    font_size: 12
    text: root.status
    size_hint: 0.25, 0.05
    color: 1,1,1,1
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.75, 'y':0.95}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for ages and I can't seem to get it.

Using kivy 1.9.0

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try change `self.status` to `MenuScreen.status` since the declaration `status = 'Text_Status'` means the variable is not a instance variable. Also try read some basic tutorials about [oo on python](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html)

Comment: @vyscond I don't know - that's how I do it my code and it seems to work for me! I wonder if it's confusing to have the label id being the same as the StringProperty.

Comment: MenuScreen.status doesn't make any difference, no errors, but no difference.

http://i.imgur.com/hXt1d7k.png

That's what I've got so far, It's trying to update the label when I press a button.

Answer (score 1):

I finally stumbled upon the answer:

```
    status = StringProperty()
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(MenuScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.status='Text_status'
def updatelabel(self):
    print("Trying to update label")
    self.status='Text_status no.2' # When I call this function, this does not update the label.
```

This now works fine.
I was missing the def __init__ function.

Comment: The problem was that your original code replaced the StringProperty with just a string, which doesn't have event behaviour or anything. Using the `__init__` (or another method) is necessary because this updates the variable for the instance, rather than replacing the class variable.

Comment: I'm curious. Do you need the `__init__`, or could you just do `status = StringProperty("Text_status")` and then just have the `updatelabel` method as before?